# Question on tensor product calculation

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Why does this tensor product result in a matrix? I would assume here given vector space $V$ and dual space $V^*$ the tensor product would be a dual function from $V^*$ acting on a vector of $V$ resulting in a scalar.

Could anyone clarify that for me? Sorry I am quite new to tensor products and didn't yet get the gist of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with a general example I think it's related. Given a finite vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$, $\dim(V) = n$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{e_1, e_2,..., e_n\}$ a base for $V$, we can define the tensor product $T :=V\otimes V$ and a base for $T$, knowing $\mathcal{A}$ could be:
$$\mathcal{B} = \{e_i \otimes e_j : e_i,e_j \in \mathcal{A}, i, j= 1,2,...,n \}$$

since it's a base every element of $T$ could be write as a linear combination with elements in $T$, for example let $v = e_1\otimes e_1 + e_n \otimes e_n$a convenient way to **write**  $v$ could be using matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &\ldots & 0\\
0 & \ddots & &\vdots \\
\vdots & &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

in the position (1,1) we have 1 corresponding to the component relative to $e_1\otimes e_1$ same for (n,n). What I'm trying to say is $v$ isn't a proper matrix but could be described very well with them, especially in this two dimensional case.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that given a basis $\{v_i\}$ of $V$, each element $v$ of $V$ can be uniquely represented as a column vector $(a_i)$ (with finitely many non-zero entries) such that $v=\sum_i a_iv_i$. Given a basis $\{w_j\}$ for $W$, each element of $W^*$ can be represented as a row vector $[b_j]$ with $b_j=f(v_j)$.

Each simple tensor $v\otimes f\in V\otimes W$ can then be written as a pairing $(a_i)\otimes[b_j]$ of a column vector and a row vector. The matrix corresponding to the linear transformation associated to this simple tensor is given by the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%20product) $M_{km}=a_kb_m$, i.e. the matrix of all products of an element of the column vector $(a_i)$ with an element of the row vector $[b_j]$. Since each tensor is a linear combination of simple tensors, we can associate to each tensor a linear combination of such Kronecker products. To see that this is well-defined, you need something like the argument below. Note that in general, this is an injective function from tensors to linear transformations, and surjective onto linear transformations with finite-dimensional image.

In particular, the identity matrix is the sum of Kronecker products of column vectors $(0,..,0,1,0,...,0)$ and row vectors $[0,..,0,1,0,..,0]$, with the $1$s in the same relative position.

More abstractly, what is happening is this. The linear functions out of the tensor product correspond to multilinear functions out of the factors. A vector space $W$ and a dual $W^*$ have by definition a bilinear function to the base field $\Bbbk$. Consequently, tensoring again with $V$ yields a linear function $(V\otimes W^*)\otimes W\cong V\otimes(W^*\otimes W)\to V\otimes\Bbbk\cong V$. By the tensor-hom adjunction, this corresponds to a trilinear function sending $(v,f,w)\mapsto vf(w)$. But this correspond to a linear function $V\otimes W^*\to\mathrm{Hom}(W,V)$ which on simple tensors acts as $v\otimes f\mapsto(w\mapsto vf(w))$.

Explicitly, each simple tensor $v\otimes f$ corresponds to a linear map sending a vector $w$ to the multiple of $v$ by the scalar $f(w)$. In particular, the linear map associated to a simple tensor $(a_i)\otimes[b_j]$ acts on basis vectors via $v_m\mapsto f(w_m)v=b_m\sum_k a_kv_k=\sum_k b_ma_kv_k$. Consequently, the matrix $M_{km}$ such that $w_m\mapsto\sum_k M_{km}v_k$ is the linear map associated to the simple tensor $(a_i)\otimes[b_j]$ is given by $M_{km}=a_kb_j$.

To see injectivity, note that given a simple tensor as a finite linear combination $\sum v_i\otimes f_i$, the resulting map is $w\mapsto\sum v_if_i(w)$. The result is the zero map only if the $v_i$ are linearly dependent. But each tensor can be written as a finite linear combination $\sum v_i\otimes f_i$ of simple tensors for a linearly independent set $\{v_i\}$, in which case we must have $f_i(w)=0$ for all $w$, i.e. $f_i=0$ for each $i$.

Surjectivity onto linear transformations with finite-dimensional image $U\subseteq V$ can be seen by choosing a basis for $V$ extending a basis for $U$. Then any linear transformation $W\to V$ is of the form $w\mapsto\sum v_if_i(w)$ for uniquely determined coefficients $f_i(w)$, hence for unique elements $f_i\in W^*$. Such a linear transformation has image in $U$ if and only if $f_i=0$ when $v_i\not\in U$, in which case $w\mapsto\sum v_if_i(w)$ is the image of the finite combination of simple tensors $\sum v_i\otimes f_i$.